# what is "segmentation fault - invalid memory reference error" in FORTRAN

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, segmentation-fault

I am receiving the following error in my Fortran code :

```
  Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

  Backtrace for this error:
  #0  0x7F80C7B46777
  #1  0x7F80C7B46D7E
  #2  0x7F80C7282D3F
  #3  0x402D1A in __mymodule_MOD_gcr_mfree
  #4  0x412175 in MAIN__ at HUHSI1.f90:?
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
  ------------------
  (program exited with code: 139)
```

1. I don't understand this error completely. What is this error?

   Number 3 indicates the following subroutine :

   ```
   SUBROUTINE gcr_Mfree(F2,Cnew,Cold,C_Fold,xm,converged)

       !**** FUNCTIONS TO BE SOLVED ****
       ! Generalized Conjugate Residual Algorithm
       ! Solves M*x=b (J*dx=-F)

       IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)

       INTEGER, intent(out)                :: converged  
       REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: F2,p,Mp             
       REAL*8, DIMENSION(:),   ALLOCATABLE :: F2V,F22V,CnewV,ColdV,C_FoldV,alpha2,r,b,Mr,xv

       ! 2D INPUT VARIABLE DIMENSIONS:
       DIMENSION F22(-2:IG+2,-2:JG+2)
       DIMENSION Cnew(-2:IG+2,-2:JG+2)
       DIMENSION Cold(-2:IG+2,-2:JG+2)
       DIMENSION C_Fold(-2:IG+2,-2:JG+2)
       DIMENSION xm(-2:IG+2,-2:JG+2)

       integer :: j,maxiter,iter
       real*8 :: tol,normr  
       !===================================================================           

       MASK = SIZE(F2)                 ! Size of F2 : (IG+5)*(JG+5)
       Print*, 'MASK IS EQUAL TO',MASK
       ALLOCATE(F2V(1:MASK))
       ALLOCATE(CnewV(1:MASK))
       ALLOCATE(ColdV(1:MASK))
       ALLOCATE(C_FoldV(1:MASK))
       ALLOCATE(xv(1:MASK))

       ALLOCATE(r(1:MASK))
       ALLOCATE(b(1:MASK))
       ALLOCATE(p(1:IG,1:JG))
       ALLOCATE(Mp(1:IG,1:JG))

       !************* RESHAPING MATRICES TO VECTORS **************
       F2V     = RESHAPE(F2    ,(/MASK/))
       ColdV   = RESHAPE(Cold  ,(/MASK/))
       CnewV   = RESHAPE(Cnew  ,(/MASK/))
       C_FoldV = RESHAPE(C_Fold,(/MASK/))

      !            Write(*,*) shape(CnewV), shape(Cnew)
      !            WRITE(*,*) 'Cold='
      !            WRITE(*,554) Cold
      !            WRITE(*,*) 'Cnew='
      !            WRITE(*,554) Cnew
      !554         FORMAT(F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F4.2,1X,F5.3,1X,F5.3,1X)     

       b       = -F2V(1:MASK)                !(why minus?)

       tol     = 5.E-2
       alpha2  = 1e-6 
       maxiter = MASK
       r       = b(1:MASK)               ! we need this when calculating r_new
       normr    = sqrt(sum( r(:)**2 ))                  !!!! Norm               

       557         FORMAT(1X,F5.2,2X,F5.2,10X,F5.2,4X,F5.2,10X,F5.2,2X,F5.2)
       WRITE(*,*) 'ColdV,CnewV'
       WRITE(*,557) ColdV,CnewV,F2V,C_FoldV,b,r
       PRINT*, 'normr=', nomr

       !************* MAIN CALCULATION ****************
       DO iter=1,maxiter

           !Get preliminary search direction
           p(:,iter) = r(:)

                           WRITE(*,*) 'p='
                           WRITE(*,558) ,p
           558             FORMAT(1X,F4.2) 

           ! Approximate the Jacobian(M) residual product
           CnewV = CnewV + alpha2 * r

           WRITE(*,*), 'CnewV='
           WRITE(*,559) ,CnewV
           559             FORMAT(1X,F4.2)

           Cnew = RESHAPE(CnewV,(/IG+5,JG+5/))                 

           !********** Call Crank-Nicolson Function               

           F22V= RESHAPE(F22,(/MASK/))

           Mr(:) = (1/alpha2)*(F22V-F2V)      !GUIDE: (The apporximated Jacobian matrix)

           Mp(:,iter) = Mr(:)

           !! Orthogonalize search direction
           do j = 1, iter-1
               p(:,iter)  = p(:,iter)  - sum( Mp(:,j) * Mp(:,iter) ) * p(:,j)
               Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) - sum( Mp(:,j) * Mp(:,iter) ) * Mp(:,j)
           enddo

           !Normalize search direction              
           p(:,iter)  =  p(:,iter) / (norm2(Mp(:,iter))) 
           Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) / (norm2(Mp(:,iter)))

           !Update solution and residual
           alpha2 = sum( r(:) * Mp(:,iter) ) / sum( Mp(:,iter)**2 )                            
           xv = xv + alpha2 * p(:,iter)
           r = r - alpha2 * Mp(:,iter)      ! where is the *(Cnew - C)?

           xm = RESHAPE(xv,(/IG+5,JG+5/)) 

           !Check convergence
           normr=sqrt(sum( r(:)**2 ))                               !!!! norm
           !fprintf('norm(r) = !g iter = !gNewLine',normr,iter+1);
           if (normr.LT.tol) then
               converged=1
               exit
           end if


       END DO 

       if (normr > tol) then
           write(*,*) 'GCR SOLUTION DID NOT CONVERGE!'
           converged=0
       end if

       RETURN
   END subroutine gcr_Mfree
   ```

   Here are a couple of things I have done to figure out why I am receiving this error:

   I have traced the values of the variables in my code by printing them step by step. I have reached this formula where I am not able to print the value for **CnewV** anymore.

   ```
   CnewV = CnewV + alpha2 * r
   ```
2. This formula is in "mymodule_MOD_gcr_mfree" which is indicated by #3 in the error message. **Why the error is not indicating any row number?**

   "r" is a vector. "alpha2" is scalar. CnewV at the RHS is a vector. Size and rank of "r" and "CnewV" are the same and the value of only one element in "CnewV" vector is **NaN**. Also, two or three elements are printed "*****" when I am trying to print them at screen.
3. when printing the matrix "p" (the format number is 558), there are much less elements in the array p. There are 221 elements in array "r", however, there are 96 in "p"

This is a complicated problem. I hope the given information is enough to understand the error.

Comment: You are accessing memory that you don't own (probably going off the end of an array).

Comment: @Carcigenicate Why I am not able to print **Cnew** at screen?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Fortran. That error message just reaks of accessing unowned memory. It's a similar error message in other low languages.

Comment: It should be useful to replace "IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)" by "implicit none" and declare all variables explicitly.

Comment: It would also help to turn on the compiler option for run-time illegal subscript checking.    e.g., in gfortran, use `-fcheck=bounds` or `-fcheck=all`

Comment: @M.S.B. I am using Geany. I have changed the compile command to **gfortran -Wall -fcheck=bounds "%f"** or the other one. Nothing changed and it compiles successfully and gives the same result.

Comment: @roygvib I changed it to **IMPLICIT NONE**. Nothing happed and I received the same error.

Comment: One of the elements of vector "r" is NaN in formula **CnewV=CnewV + alpha2 * r**. Do you think it is because of the NaN? It will continue to calculate in the case of NaN element in an array in MATLAB. how about Fortran?

Comment: @Vahid no, NaN is a valid floating point value and if it were going to cause an error (depends on a few things) it would be a floating point signal and you would get a different error. SIGSEGV aka signal 11 is a generic "you tried to access memory you weren't allowed to" error. It can arise from double-deallocation, buffer overruns, etc. Are all of your allocations successful? You are not checking that... Also try adding `-g -fbacktrace` (if using gfortran) or `-g -traceback` (if using ifort) to your compile command to get debug symbols and hopefully more information when you segfault

Comment: In addition to my answer, do you really want to provide space for potentially storing IG*JG iterations? If you get beyond a couple of hundred points this looks as if it could blow out horribly. Disregard if it's only for a small toy problem.

Comment: It is a waste of yours and everyone's time to search for bugs in your code which can be easily identified by the compiler. Compile with `gfortran -g3 -fcheck=all -Wall -fbacktrace`. If you use recent enough version of gfortran add also `-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak`. Read carefully the manual of the compiler https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html  Other compilers have similar flags in their compiler.

Comment: Worth pointing out, I think, that `-fcheck=bounds` will not lead to the compiler raising errors but inserting code so that array-bound errors are caught, and reported, at run-time.  It's not entirely clear that OP understands this.

Comment: @VladimirF I would be happy to solve my issue and waste neither my time nor the others. By the way, none of your compile commands worked. The 1st one ends with **gfortran: fatal error: no input files** and the second one '-fsanitize' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Comment: @casey I have tried to get rid of allocating part of the code yesterday and I think it helped a lot. I am working on it right now... None of the compilation commands at everyone's comments are helping at all. Why I am not receiving any detailed error referring to a line or etc.?

Comment: Read what I write and what the compiler writes *carefully*. "No input files" mean you forgot to include the file you are compiling! I also wrote you must have recent version of the compiler to use `-fsanitize`. **Please do use -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -Wall** you will save everyone's time, yours included.

Comment: @Vahid in case the comment above still eludes you, if you previously used a command like `gfortran -o blah something.f90` then now use `gfortran -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -Wall -o blah something.f90`.  We are not giving you a whole command line, just options you need to add to your compilation.  Recompile all your source with these options.

Comment: @RussF It is the nature of the GCR method. The number of successful iterations which ends convergence is less than the number of grid points in the system. The grid points exceed 3000 in the domain. But be aware that it is much better than working with large Jacobian matrix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The answer to question 1** :
Segmentation error is due to memory conflicts. In this case, the error is generated due to wrong allocation of variables. Also, we should set variable bound limits.

Wrong :

```
CnewV = CnewV + alpha2 * r
```

Corrected:

```
CnewV(0:IG,0:JG) = CnewV(0:IG,0:JG) + alpha2 * r(0:IG,0:JG)
```

**The answer to question 2** : 
I believe this is a compiler bug. I checked other compilers too and none were able to address this type of error.

**The answer to question 3** : 
The low number of elements in an array inside a function/subroutine is due to improperly variable setting during calling the function/subroutine. If you get this error you should add that variable to list of variables which should be called.

**Still Pointer assignemnt is not working properly:** 
I have managed to overcome segmentation error and the whole code compiles fine. However, I receive NaN numbers after 3rd iteration.

The below test code is intended to show the source of problem. I have tried the following solution. however, I am not able to write the vector 'Mr' to column's of target matrix 'Mp' at each iteration!

```
 program ptrtest

 real, pointer, CONTIGUOUS :: Mr(:)
 real, pointer, CONTIGUOUS :: Mp(:,:)
 real, DIMENSION(9) ::abc


 integer :: n = 2
 iter=3

 Do i=1,iter

 alpha2 = 2
 allocate(Mr(n**2))
 abc= 42

 Mr(1:n**2) = 0.5 * abc(1:n**2)
 write(*,*) 'Mr='
 write(*,555) Mr

 Mr(1:n**2) => Mp(1:n**2,1:1) 

 WRITE(*,*) 'Mp='
 WRITE(*,555) Mp

 end do

 555  FORMAT(F12.4,1X) 


 end program ptrtest
```

Error :

```
 gfortran -Wall -fcheck=all "Pointer.f95" (in directory: /home/vahid/Dropbox/To Move folder/Geany/Test_Pointer application)
 Pointer.f95:25.3:
 Mr(1:n**2) => Mp(1:n**2,1:i)
 1
 Error: Incompatible ranks 1 and 2 in assignment at (1)
 Compilation failed.
```

I have tried `Mp(1:n**2,1:i) => Mr(1:n**2)`. this overcomes compilation error. however, Mp is not target and the elements of vector are rewritten to 1st column of the matrix at each iteration.

Comment: Hi @Vahid, the added code says `Mr( 1:n**2 ) => Mp( 1:n**2, 1:1 )`, while the error message says `Mr( 1:n**2 ) = Mp(1:n**2,1:i )`. Which is your desired statement? (The latter is not in the added code...) Do you want to make an array pointer to the i-th column of Mp(:,:)? Also,  since Mp is not allocated, it cannot be pointed to by Mr!

Comment: I feel you might have a mixed understanding of Fortran array (pointer) and Matlab arrays. In Matlab arrays, we can do `Mp( 1:n**2, i ) = Mr( 1:n**2 )` even if the left-hand side is not defined before. On the other hand, Fortran arrays have to be allocated as `allocate( Mp( 1:n**2, 1:Niter ) )` before the iteration begins. One then performs `Mp( 1:n**2, i ) = Mr( 1:n**2 )` inside the iteration. In other words, Matlab's array can grow its size automatically as needed, while Fortran's array cannot. Even if you use array pointers, this fact does not change (details are omitted...)

Comment: @roygvib **EXPLANATION:** I want to cast a 1D array into column of 2D array in a loop. At 1st iteration the size of this 2D array is same as the 1D array. So. There should be no problem to cast it. At 2nd iteration, 1D array is going to have different elements. I want to cast it to 2nd column of 2D array. this continues and the algorithm is such that you can not guess the number of columns of 2D array to allocate it before starting calculation.

Comment: @roygvib I completely understand your last comment. But there should be a way in Fortran to cast a 1D array into columns of 2D array as I want at each iteration. I haven't found any help/example at Internet for my problem till now. I got the above idea form this webpage: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/475663 . Can I use {TRANSFER or type(c_ptr)} ? Although I dont know what exactly the 2nd one does?

Comment: Yes, because you are using an iterative algorithm, the necessary number of iteration for convergence is unknown _in principle_. But _in practice_, we should have some empirical knowledge as to how many iterations are usually needed for a particular problem (for example, I guess you have such experience with Matlab... correct?) Then the "Fortran" way is to set Niter (= the number of columns of 2D array) to some reasonable "guess" value, which is, say, two times larger than what is empirically needed. Then we allocate Mp( ..., Niter ) before the iteration begins.

Comment: By "I want to cast a 1D array into column of 2D array", do you mean that you want to copy a 1D array (here, Mr) to the i-th column of 2D array (here, Mp)? Then you need to write as Mp( :, i ) = Mr( : ). If you want to make an alias (or pointer) of the i-th column of Mp(:,:), then you need to write as Mr => Mp( :, i ). So the statement is different depending on what you want to achieve... Also, in either case, we must allocate Mp(:,:) before the iteration loop begins.

Answer (score 2):

You are exceeding the array bounds on both `p` and `Mp` which are both dimensioned `(1:IG,1:JG)`. The outer loop for iter runs from 1 to `maxiter=MASK=(IG+5)*(JG+5)` eventually resulting in illegal memory accesses for `p(:,iter)`. Also the line

```
p(:,iter)=r(:)
```

is a mismatch since `r` has size=MASK.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning. The idea is to store the vector "r" into the columns of matrix p. The vector "r" updates at each iteration.